# Array resource returning integer

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm just getting into android app development. I'm trying to find the value of an item in an array resource from the index, but the resource is returning an integer rather than an array.
I have this piece of code:

```
                pop1.setItems(R.array.PopupMenuListItems, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which ) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Selected " + R.array.PopupMenuListItems, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

and when the Toast message shows, it shows "Selected 2131492864", and I can't index an integer.

So, my question is how can I convert R.array.PopupMenuListItems into an array rather than an integer, so I can use R.array.PopupMenuListItems[which]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getStringArray` for getting Array from resources :

```
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which ) {
 String[] arrAllData = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.PopupMenuListItems2);
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                 "Selected " + arrAllData[which], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, will make as answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: @BraydonDavis: One more suggestion: we can also pass String Array to `setItems` method so instead of reading Array from resources again and again read it only one time before `pop1.setItems` line and use in both places

Answer (score 1):

Access like this way,

```
 String[]  mTestArray =  = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.testArray);
```